# Install IBM Plex fonts in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, overleaf

To write my latex projects I use Overleaf (XeLatex). The font family I use is IBM-Plex. A few days ago, the IBM team made an update. On CTAN I found that this font family has had the last update in 2019.

I have done the following steps:

1. download the font family to the folder fonts in root directory of my project in Overleaf
2. Add this lines into the main.tex

   ```
   %% Main font for Latin text
   \setmainfont{IBMPlexSansCondensed}[
       Path=./fonts/IBM-Plex-Sans-Condensed/,
       Extension = .otf,
       UprightFont=*-Regular,
       BoldFont=*-Bold,
       BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
       ItalicFont=*-Italic
       ]
   ```

IBM Plex has a lot more font styles. Here is the complete list. How do I activate this styles? Bold is `\textbf{}` or `\bfseries`, Mono is `\texttt{}`. Is it possible to get a list of comands?

- Bold BoldItalic
- ExtraLight ExtraLightItalic
- Light LightItalic
- Medium MediumItalic
- Regular Italic
- SemiBold SemiBoldItalic
- Text TextItalic
- Thin ThinItalic

The following options select lighter bold fonts:

- sb semibold
- mb medium
- tx text

and the following options select lighter regular fonts:

- l  light
- el extralight
- t  thin

For slightly heavier regular fonts use the options

txmd textmd

The nomap option to plex-mono will suppress the tex-text
mapping of TeX "smart quotes" and other ligatures into
unicode glyphs for xeLaTeX and luaLaTeX.

The OpenType fonts were obtained from

https://github.com/IBM/plex/

How do I use the semibold, medium and tx fonts?

Comment: have you tried using `lualatex` instead? XeLaTeX can be notoriously difficult to get to use local fonts whereas `lualatex` is more forgiving.

Comment: Also explain what you mean by `does not work`? Does it give you an error, if so please cite it. Have you looked for clues in the log file.